# Return value of property based on property name

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

How do I build expression tree in C# that returns value of a property based on the name of the property

```
Func<Foo, long> getValue(string propertyName)
{
    // i think that the beginning of the expression tree would look like this
    // but i'm not sure this is correct
    var inputParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo));
    var desiredProperty = typeof(Foo).GetProperty(propertyName);
    var valueOfProperty = Expression.Property(inputParameter, desiredProperty);
    // ... ???   todo: expression that returns value
}
```

Call to this function looks like this which is part of another expression that is passed to Linq's Select method:

```
value = getValue("Bar").Invoke(FooInstance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be enough:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, long>>(valueOfProperty, inputParameter);
return lambda.Compile();
```

Anyway - what's the purpose for building Expression when you could get value directly via reflection?

```
return someFoo => (long)desiredProperty.GetValue(someFoo);
```

Comment: Reflection works too, thanks! I wasn't sure reflection would work with SQL Server Linq IQueryable provider.

Comment: that is great, with reflection I was able to omit getValue function altogether and write 
`value = (long)typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar").GetValue(FooInstance)`